# hacker news api + angular.js issue loading certain story types

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am building a hacker news client using the official hacker news firebase api and angular.js. I am having an issue loading the 'jobstories' posts. The id's of the stories are logged to the console, however, nothing is rendering on the screen. My code works when getting 'topstories', 'maxitem', and 'showstories', though so I'm fairly puzzled. Here is a link to the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ogUYNqTQvS9DFPRsd2b7?p=preview).

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngColorThis', 'ngTouch']).factory('HackerNews', function() {
return new Firebase('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0');});

angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.services']).controller('AppController', [
'$scope', '$sce', '$timeout', '$window', '$q', 'HackerNews', function($scope, $sce, $timeout, $window, $q, HackerNews) {
$scope.section = 'top';
$scope.gotoStory = function(story) {
  $scope.currentStory = story;
  $scope.storyUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(story.url);
  return $scope.navi.pushPage(cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open(story.url, '_blank', {toolbar: {
    height: 44,
    color: 'transparent'
}, closeButton: {
    image: 'ic_cancel_black',
    imagePressed: 'close_pressed',
    align: 'left',
    event: 'closePressed'
}}));
};
$scope.loadUrl = function(url) {
  return $window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
};
return $scope.getStory = function(id) {
  var deferred, timer;
  deferred = $q.defer();
  timer = $timeout(deferred.resolve, 1000);
  HackerNews.child("item/" + id).once('value', function(data) {
    var item;
    item = data.val();
    if (item && item.type === 'story' && !item.deleted && item.url) {
      $timeout.cancel(timer);
      return deferred.resolve(item);
    } else {
      $timeout.cancel(timer);
      return deferred.resolve();
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
}
]).controller('JobController', [
'$scope', '$q', 'HackerNews', function($scope, $q, HackerNews) {
$scope.stories = [];
$scope.getJobStories = function() {
  return HackerNews.child('jobstories').once('value', function(data) {
    var i, id, jobId, len, promises;
    console.log(data.val());
    jobId = data.val();
    promises = []; 
    for (i = 0, len = jobId.length; i < len; i++) {
      id = jobId[i];
      promises.push($scope.getStory(id));
    }
    return $q.all(promises).then(function(stories) {
      stories = stories.filter(function(story) {
        return typeof story !== 'undefined';
      });
      if (stories.length > 0) {
        return $scope.stories = stories;
      }
    });
  });
};
return HackerNews.child('jobstories').on('value',   $scope.getJobStories);
}
]);

      <ons-template id="jobs.html">
        <ons-navigator var="navi">
            <ons-list  ng-controller="JobController">            
              <ons-list-item  modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="story in stories" ng-click="gotoStory(story); showme=true;">   
                <div ng-hide="showme">  
                  <div style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">   
                    <span color-this="color" data-color="story.title" class="story-title">{{ story.title }}</span>           
                    <span color-this="color" data-color="story" class="story-site">({{ story.url | urlToHost }})</span>            
                    <span style="display:inline" class="story-info">{{ story.score }} points by</span><span style="display:inline" color-this="color" data-color="story.title" class="story-info"> {{ story.by }} </span><span style="display:inline" class="story-info">{{ story.time | timeAgo }}</span>           
                  </div>           
                </div>           
                <div ng-show="showme" style="opacity:0.4" color-this="background" data-color="story.title">                      
                  <div style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">            
                    <span class="story-title">{{ story.title }}</span>             
                    <span color-this="color" data-color="story" class="story-site">({{ story.url | urlToHost }})</span>              
                    <span class="story-info">{{ story.score }} points by {{ story.by }} {{ story.time | timeAgo }}</span>            
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ons-list-item>
           </ons-navigator>
         </ons-template>
```

Comment: You haven't provided the code for the `HackerNews` service. Nor have you provided a way to reproduce this (e.g., the template that invokes this controller function).  You can't just provide a link to the plunkr; the shortest amount of code needed to reproduce this issue should be in the question itself. If plunkr goes down or that code changes, it is no longer helpful for future visitors.

Comment: I just updated my post. All the pertinent code should be there now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured out what was wrong. I had the line `if (item && item.type === 'story' && !item. DELETED&& item.url)` in which I limited the results to items of the type "story." The jobs posts actually have a type equal to "job" so these posts were not being allowed. I removed the condition specifying item type and was able to render the job posts to the screen.